# MYSQL REGEXP_SUBSTR: get string or ip out of text

Tags: mysql, regexp-substr, rlike

I struggle through a complex query and need help with a *REGEXP_SUBSTR* command being used in the *WHERE CLAUSE*:
In deed this are two questions.

1. given three possible records, I want to get the part between the brackets, but only if they match something that looks like an ip. In one case the question is simply between brackets like "*[192.168.178.21]*"
2. other case is the text is like "*sender=<some192-168-178-12.example.here>*"

Case 1:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('This is a sample of [192.168.178.12] containing relevant data','(?<=[ ]\[)[^\]]#]+') AS sender
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('This is a sample of [dyn-192-168-178-12.example.com] containing relevant data','(?<=[ ]\[)[^\]]#]+') AS sender
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('This is a sample of [only.example com] containing relevant data','(?<=[ ]\[)[^\]]#]+') AS sender
```

The problem above is that escaping does not work the way I've expected.
Expected would be:

```
127.0.0.1
dyn.127.0.0.1.example.com
NULL
```

Case 2:

If I search in the field using the *WHERE CLAUSE* I have limited success with

```
WHERE ( sndtext RLIKE ' sender=\\<.*[0-9]{1,3}(.|-|_)[0-9]{1,3}(.|-|_)[0-9]{1,3}(.|-|_)[0-9]{1,3}.*\\>')
```

but the match is too broad, it needs to stop at the '>'

How can I achieve both solution in a *WHERE CLAUSE*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might not be perfekt but my solution was (less escaping):

```
SELECT 
   REGEXP_SUBSTR(msgtext, '(?<=[[])[^]]+') AS ip,
   REGEXP_SUBSTR(msgtext,'(?<=[ ]sndtext=<)[^>]+') AS txt
FROM txtmessage m
   WHERE msgtext RLIKE ' sndtext=<.*([0-9]{1,3}[[:punct:]]){3}[0-9]{1,3}[^>]'
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in the [MySQL online tester](https://extendsclass.com/mysql-online.html) if I'm understanding what you are looking for correctly.

```
with tbl(id, data) as (
  select 1, 'This is a sample of [192.168.178.12] containing relevant data' from dual union all
  select 2, 'This is a sample of [dyn-192-168-178-12.example.com] containing relevant data' from dual union all
  select 3, 'This is a sample of [only.example com] containing relevant data' from dual union all
  select 4, 'sender=<some192-168-178-12.example.here>' from dual
)
select id, data 
from tbl
where ( data RLIKE '^.*(\\[|\\<).*[0-9]{1,3}(\\.|\\-)[0-9]{1,3}(\\.|\\-)[0-9]{1,3}(\\.|\\-)[0-9]{1,3}.*(\\]|\\>).*$');
```